# Tortoise svn Log history revert to revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I believe one of my colleagues reverted a file to a previous revision, but I am not able to find out from which revision he reverted. I cannot see anything from the revisionj graph or log history. I have attached a picture showing a simple example where the current version (261) is actually a reverted file from another revision (207) frI am using Tortoise SVN v.1.9.

Do anyone have an idea on how to trace this?

[Revision graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPmbn.png)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your revision graph, it appears that your colleague did this reversion not by performing a [reverse merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo), but by simply replacing his working copy's version of the file with an export of a previous revision and committing it.

Which means that there's no way to trace it back. You're left with either asking him what he did, or comparing the `HEAD` revision with each older revision until you find an exact match.